# MySQL between not gathering last date

Tags: mysql

**Table**

```
+--+------------+
|Id|   Date     |
+--+------------+
|1 | 2017-08-08 |
+--+------------+
|2 | 2017-08-23 |
+--+------------+
|3 | 2017-08-23 |
+--+------------+
|4 | 2017-08-24 |
+--+------------+
|5 | 2017-08-24 |
+--+------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM BoxExits WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-08-08' AND '2017-08-24'
```

**Problem**

When i execute the query i receive the expected dated (from id 1 to 3) except for all rows that contains this date 2017-08-24 (from id 4 to 5) the only way to gather it is by adding one day so that the query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM BoxExits WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-08-08' AND '2017-08-25'
```

In this case is will retrieve all rows that contains this date 2017-08-24 (from id 4 to 5), since the user is the one that will chose the dates i don't want to force him to add one day to the date is looking for.

So how can i do it to the query give me also the max date (2017-08-24)?

**My Research**

While Searching i didn't find much except for this:

```
SELECT * FROM BoxExits WHERE Date >= '2017-08-08' AND Date <= '2017-08-24'
```

since the query says `Date <= '2017-08-24'` 2017-08-24 should be included but the problem maintains.

**Environment Test**
I Tested it in phpmyadmin and a c# program that i am creating and both are giving me the same result (rows from 1 to 3).

Comment: What type is your `Date` column?

Comment: I think you should need betwee like @scaisedge mentioned in his answer. In MySQL we use `between` for matching dates

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is DateTime but scaisedge already awnserd.

Comment: @Noob i was already using between just see my question

Comment: @pekira You have some datetime like `2017-08-24 12:00:00` which is greater than `2017-08-24 00:00:00` which is what the raw date becomes in the comparison.

Comment: What's this got to do with c?

Comment: @Strawberry i only add c# because stackoverflow recommended to but if it shouldn't be there i can remove it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be that you have a datetime for Date so try using only the date part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BoxExits 
WHERE DATE(Date) BETWEEN '2017-08-08' AND '2017-08-24'
```

Comment: But what if there is an index of the Date column? Will this cause a missed index by the engine?

Comment: the question by OP if for not get  the expected  result for a between  .. on date  .. the reason is that the OP compare a datetime with a date value  so the result don't match as expected .. for the index ond the date column ..normally  a function on a column can invalid the use of index  ..but for this the OP can also create and index for DATE(date)

Comment: If this were true then the result would show a time component !?!? And, remembering that this is MySQL, I'm not sure what's meant by creating an 'index for DATE(date)'

Comment: in mysql 5.7.5 is possible using generated column  and before .. if the performance are so important is possibile manage this istuation using a trigger for build the proper column values ..

Answer (score 1):

**it is correct format**
use `date()` function which get date only from datetime. Range of result include both date

```
SELECT * 
FROM BoxExits 
WHERE date(Date) BETWEEN '2017-08-08' AND '2017-08-24'
```